# pandas - remove specific sequence from column

Tags: python, pandas, graph, sequence, networkx

I want to remove specific sequences from my column, because they appear a lot and don't give me a lot of extra information. The database consists of edges between nodes. In this case, there will be an edge between node 1 and node 1, node 1 and node 2, node 2 and node 3.....

However, the edge 1-5 happens around 80.000 times in the real database. I want to filter those out, only keeping the 'not so common' interactions.

Lets say my dataframe looks like this

```
>>> datatry
   num  line    
0   1    56
1   1    90  
2   2    66  
3   3    4  
4   1    23  
5   5    22  
6   3    144
7   5    33
```

What I have so far was removing a sequence that was only repeating itself:

```
c1 = datatry['num'].eq('1')
c2 = datatry['num'].eq(datatry['num'].shift(1))
datatry2 = datatry[(c1 & ~c2) | ~(c1)]
```

How could I alter the code above (that removes all the rows that repeat the integer 1 and keeps only the first row with the value 1) to code that removes all rows that are a specific sequence? For example: a 1 and then a 5? In this case, I want to remove both the row with value 1 and the row with value 5 that appear in that sequence. My end result would ideally be:

```
>>> datatry
   num  line    
0   1    56
1   1    90  
2   2    66  
3   3    4  
4   3    144
5   5    33
```

Comment: You don't explain at all what the specific sequence is. Why are you removing the 3rd `1` and the first `5` in this? whats special about those that you want to remove them?

Comment: @MattW. i have edited the question to hopefully make it a bit more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def find_drops(seq, df):
    if seq:
        m = np.logical_and.reduce([df.num.shift(-i).eq(seq[i]) for i in range(len(seq))])
        if len(seq) == 1:
            return pd.Series(m, index=df.index)
        else:
            return pd.Series(m, index=df.index).replace({False: np.NaN}).ffill(limit=len(seq)-1).fillna(False)
    else:
        return pd.Series(False, index=df.index)


find_drops([1], df)
#0     True
#1     True
#2    False
#3    False
#4     True
#5    False
#6    False
#7    False
#dtype: bool

find_drops([1,1,2,3], df)
#0     True
#1     True
#2     True
#3     True
#4    False
#5    False
#6    False
#7    False
#dtype: bool
```

Then just use those Series to slice `df[~find_drops([1,5], df)]`

Comment: Works like a charm! However, when I try to match this boolean index to my dataframe, I get the error that the boolean series are unalignable (the indexed object and the boolean series do not match).

Comment: @intStdu try it now. I added `index=df.index` to the other returns, so now it should match.

Comment: i have another question, how could i instead of filtering the sequence completely, now replace the sequence with a num value that is generated automatically at the location of the first value of the sequence? for instance, the sequence 1,5 becoming 1, the sequence 1,1,2 becoming 2, etc? the resulting df will now be: 2,3,1,3,5.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html)? That has a default value of `keep=first`. So you can simply do:

```
datatry.loc[datatry['num'].duplicated(), :]
```